# How to validate number and capital letter in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate password :

- contain at least 1 number
- contain at least 1 capital letter (uppercase)
- contain at least 1 normal letter (lowercase)

I used this code

```
function validate()
{   
    var a=document.getElementById("pass").value
    var b=0
    var c=0
    var d=0;
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[i].toUpperCase())
            b++;
        if(a[i]==a[i].toLowerCase())
            c++;
        if(!isNaN(a[i]))
            d++;
    }
    if(a=="")
    {
        alert("Password must be filled")
    }
    else if(a)
    {
        alert("Total capital letter "+b)
        alert("Total normal letter "+c)
        alert("Total number"+d)
    }   
}
```

One thing that make me confuse is why if I input a number, it also count as uppercase letter???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1".toUpperCase == "1" ! What do you say about that :)
You could do your checking like this:

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if('A' <= a[i] && a[i] <= 'Z') // check if you have an uppercase
            b++;
        if('a' <= a[i] && a[i] <= 'z') // check if you have a lowercase
            c++;
        if('0' <= a[i] && a[i] <= '9') // check if you have a numeric
            d++;
    }
```

Now if b, c, or d equals 0, there is a problem.

Comment: thanks dude, it's works :)
to solve the problem i use 
if(0 <= a[i] && a[i] <= 9) without ''

Comment: I'm glad to be usefull! Regular expressions are more suitables for this kind of validations, but I suspected that you aren't very familiar with those and your programming thinking needs some improvements (the code you posted is quite bad) and that's why I posted this solution similar to yours.

Comment: You're right.. I'm a newbie in javascript coz I started learn that last Thursday >.<

Answer (score 9):

Regular expressions are more suitable for this. Consider:

```
var containsDigits = /[0-9]/.test(password)
var containsUpper = /[A-Z]/.test(password)
var containsLower = /[a-z]/.test(password)

if (containsDigits && containsUpper && containsLower)
....ok
```

A more compact but less compatible option is to use a boolean aggregate over an array of regexes:

```
var rules = [/[0-9]/, /[A-Z]/, /[a-z]/]
var passwordOk = rules.every(function(r) { return r.test(password) });
```

Docs: [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: how to use containsDigits / containsUpper / containsLower? Are those syntax? I tried if(a[i]==containsUpper()) in for, it didn't work

Comment: No, these are variables, just like a, b, c in your code. I added some `var`s for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() will still return the character if it's not able to be converted, so your tests will succeed for numbers.

Instead, you should check first that `isNaN(a[i])` is true before testing using toLowerCase/toUpperCase.

Answer (score 0):

The very short way could be:

```
var pwd = document.getElementById("pass").value,
    valid = Number(/\d/.test('1abcD'))+
            Number(/[a-z]/.test('1abcD'))+
            Number(/[A-Z]/.test('1abcD')) === 3;
```