# javascript : validate upper case and lower case

Tags: javascript, validation

Is there any option to validate minimum **2 lower case** and **2 upper case** when checking case ?
here is the condition which I am using.

```
function HasMixedCase(passwd){
    if(passwd.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ku4mg/

Comment: `passwd.replace(/[A-Z]/g,'').length > 2`

Comment: this might help too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186297/how-to-validate-number-and-capital-letter-in-javascript

Comment: As a side note, I would highly recommend against forcing arbitrary password choice restrictions on your users. `ieatbaconsandwicheslikeitaintnothang`, for example, is quite possibly secure enough to survive the heat death of the universe despite being all low-case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edited to factor in plalx's comment:

```
var m;
if( !(m = passwd.match(/[a-z]/g)) || m.length < 2) return false;
if( !(m = passwd.match(/[A-Z]/g)) || m.length < 2) return false;
return true;
```

Trying to do too much in a single regex is a recipe for disaster, with the most common result being catastrophic backtracking.

Similarly, it makes your code more readable to do one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Altough @NietTheDarkAbsol's answer shows a perfectly valid way I would advise you to avoid doing too much in your functions. Do not be afraid of splitting logic into multiple maintainable functions.

```
function textCaseStats(text) {
    return {
        upper: (text.match(/[a-z]/g) || []).length,
        lower: (text.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length
    };
}

function hasMixedCase(password) {
    var caseStats = textCaseStats(password);

    return caseStats.lower >= 2 && caseStats.upper >= 2;
}
```